# how to calculate total business added by the employees individually

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like employees and doctorsrating.

In employees table contains list of registered employees with columns of emp_bioid and emp_name and doctorspoints emp_bioid, points, pointsname, doctor_name, createdAt of columns.

Employees will add points for doctors which will stored by the emp_bioid. My question is i want to count total records added by the each and every employees.

I have tried this query but the business count was wrong.

```
SELECT emp_bioid, COUNT(*) as Doctor (SELECT emp_name from employees where emp_bioid = doctorsrating.emp_bioid) as emp_name FROM doctorsrating 
WHERE createdAt between '2021-03-01' AND '2021-03-24' GROUP BY emp_bioid
```

Comment: Please remove the javascript tag from this question as it is not related.

Comment: provide some sample data as textual CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts and show desired outout for this data with explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a join and group by both columns (id and name) as below:

```
SELECT e.emp_bioid, e.emp_name, COUNT(*) 
FROM employees e
JOIN doctorsrating dr ON e.emp_bioid = dr.emp_bioid
WHERE dr.createdAt between '2021-03-01' AND '2021-03-24' GROUP BY e.emp_bioid, e.emp_name
```

Comment: how will I get the individual rating count of records added by every employee with this query

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept my answer as well. If you want all rating without the limitation of the date range you can just remove the WHERE clause. Or am I misunderstanding what you mean? 

SELECT e.emp_bioid, e.emp_name, COUNT(*) 
FROM employees e
JOIN doctorsrating dr ON e.emp_bioid = dr.emp_bioid
GROUP BY e.emp_bioid, e.emp_name